# XUbuntu 20.04 won't connect to wired router/internet

Tags: xubuntu, internet, ipv4

XUbuntu 20.04 won't connect to wired router/internet using my computer, the live CD, or live CD for 18.x or 16.x. These had worked before without problem. Other computers running 18.x still work and my desktop still connects using Windows 10 but not when I boot into XUbuntu. I've tried a couple of solutions posted and one worked temporarily but failed to connect on next boot up. Please let me know what you need from me to trouble shoot this problem. Thanks.

@heynnema Thanks for you help.

Wired network is mix of purchased and home-made cables down to Cat-5 but properly assembled. DSL modem-router (with WiFi) with switch between. All 10/100. Router may go up to 1000. Network wrks fine with other XUbuntu 18.04 (32 bit) computers and the HP-elite 800 64 bit desktop under Windows 10. Used to work with all versions of XUbuntu until a month or two ago (including the live cds).

01-network-manager-all.yaml

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: NetworkManager
    ethernets:
        eno1:
            dhcp4: yes
            dhcp6: no
```

I edited that file according to other solutions I had found and it worked briefly.

sudo lshw -C network

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I217-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 04
       serial: 8c:dc:d4:25:f2:71
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.13-4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:27 memory:f7c00000-f7c1ffff memory:f7c3d000-f7c3dfff ioport:f080(size=32)
```

I'm really curious why the live cds would stop connecting to the network/internet when they worked on the same set-up not long ago.

@heynnema
I edited the netplan *.yaml file back to it's original state and rebooted. That plus "setting" the cable connectors yet again seems to work and explains the problem. Also:

```
$ tracepath www.google.com
tracepath: www.google.com: No address associated with hostname
$ tracepath 8.8.8.8
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                      pmtu 1500
 1:  Broadcom.Home                                         1.406ms 
 1:  Broadcom.Home                                         1.224ms 
 2:  Broadcom.Home                                         1.170ms pmtu 1492
 2:  172.16.2.1                                           26.823ms 
 3:  vl-3611.tor01ad-aro22.ne.fibernetics.ca              43.601ms 
 4:  no reply
 5:  ip-49.50.99.216.dsl-cust.ca.inter.net                26.673ms 
 6:  google-b.ip4.torontointernetxchange.net              26.514ms asymm  9 
 7:  no reply
```

I suppose that the mtu you asked for is in there.

Comment: Perhaps you need to reboot that router.

Comment: Yes, I have tried rebooting the router more than once.  Thanks, though.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and (if it exists) `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Describe your network cabling from the computer to the router/modem. Are you using cat 5e or cat 6 cables? Home-made or purchased cables? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema  - I added the info you requested to my question but it didn't display the same as in terminal. I hope you can make sense of it.

Comment: When pasting data into your question, select the pasted text, then click the {} button to format it to human-readable. I fixed it for you. See my initial answer. Report back.

Comment: Sorry for being a newbie at this but I thought I did what you requested.

Further info:
Previously fixed using article: "networking - Ubuntu 20.04 Connection failed - Ask Ubuntu.pdf" update 3 section plus edit etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml as shown. 
Had to switch order of instruction due to file not found error but it worked after reboot. Did software update fine. Failed days after that.

Comment: You did. I just needed to instruct you on how to format it :-) We were all newbies once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**netplan**

Edit your /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml to look like this...

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

Confirm that your "Wired Connection" profile has correct settings. Delete any other ethernet profiles not required.

`reboot`

**network cabling**

To clarify...

You're using homemade or cat 5 cables, correct? Cat 5e is really the minimum. Change the cable from the computer to the switch to a 5e cable, and reboot the computer/switch/router, and see if ethernet works then.

Your ethernet switch is only 10/100, correct? And the router is 10/100/1000, correct? Why not use a 10/100/1000 switch? I ask because your computer connection is only at 100Mb... it could be 10x faster.

**DSL**

What is your MTU set at in the "Wired Connection" profile?

Install `tracepath`...

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install iputils-tracepath`

Edit your question and show me...

`tracepath www.google.com`

**Update #1:**

<strike>Re-seating ethernet cables solved the connection problem.</strike>

**Update #2:**

The MTU setting in your "Wired Connection" profile should be 1492 because of DSL.

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129600/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-xubuntu-20-04-wont-connect-to-wired-router-int).

Comment: @ThomasWard Thanks but now I can't continue the discussion/trouble-shooting.

Comment: @heynnema Modem/router is all-in-one, model Smart RG SR630n with 4 ethernet lan ports (plus others and WiFi). My desktop does not have wireless capability. I have full admin priveleges and Access Control appears to be enabled.

Comment: @AtoZ007 Click on the [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129600/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-xubuntu-20-04-wont-connect-to-wired-router-int) link, and we can continue there. In the mean time, confirm that the correct MAC address is in Access Control, or temporarily turn off AC and see if things start working.